# Writing Spark DataFrame to CSV

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a Spark dataframe to a CSV, but since some of the columns of the dataframe have an array, like so:

```
|ID|ArrayOfString|Age|Gender|
+--+-------------+---+------+
|1 | [A,B,D]     |22 | F    |
|2 | [A,Y]       |42 | M    |
|3 | [X]         |60 | F    |
+--+-------------+---+------+
```

I get an error:
`CSV data source does not support array<string> data type`

So, I'd like to iterate over the columns of the dataframe, and for the ones that are of type array, I'd like to stringify them `mkString(", ")`

I found the following link, that does something similar in Python:
https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/08/05/spark-data-frame-check-for-any-column-values-with-n-and-y-and-convert-the-corresponding-column-to-boolean-using-pyspark/

I need to do it in Scala, and my attempt is:\

```scala
df.dtypes.map(dtype => 
{
  val colName = dtype[0]
  val colType = dtype[1]

  if (colType.contains("ArrayType")) {
    df = df.withColumn(colName, df.col(colName).mkString(", ")).drop(df[colName])
  }
})
```

But I'm a beginner in Scala, and can't figure out how to fix this. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assemble a list of all `ArrayType` columns and traverse the list using `foldLeft` to stringify the array columns:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq("A", "B", "C"), 22, "F"),
  (2, Seq("A", "Y"), 42, "M"),
  (3, Seq("X"), 60, "F")
).toDF("ID", "ArrayOfString", "Age", "Gender")

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val arrTypeCols = df.schema.fields.collect{
  case StructField(name, ArrayType(_, _), _, _) => name
}
// arrTypeCols: Array[String] = Array(ArrayOfString)

val df2 = arrTypeCols.foldLeft( df )( (acc, c) =>
  acc.withColumn( c, concat_ws(", ", df(c)) )
)

df2.show
// +---+-------------+---+------+
// | ID|ArrayOfString|Age|Gender|
// +---+-------------+---+------+
// |  1|      A, B, C| 22|     F|
// |  2|         A, Y| 42|     M|
// |  3|            X| 60|     F|
// +---+-------------+---+------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh Maharjan.  It's an interesting problem strangely flagged duplicate, despite major difference pointed out by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a `udf` function to change the *array columns* to *string columns*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val arrayToStringUdf = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => array.mkString(", "))
```

And **since you are unaware of the *arrayType column names*, you will need a *recursive function* to iterate through `dataframe` columns to check for `ArrayType` and call the `udf` function**

```
def recursiveFunction(dataFrame: DataFrame, dataTypes: List[Tuple2[String, String]]) : DataFrame = dataTypes match {
  case x :: y => if (x._2.contains("ArrayType")) {
      recursiveFunction(dataFrame.withColumn(x._1, arrayToStringUdf(col(x._1))), y)
    }
    else{
      recursiveFunction(dataFrame, y)
    }
  case _ => dataFrame
}
```

You can create a *list* of `Tuple2(colName, colType)` to be iterated in the *recursive function*

```
val dataTypes = df.dtypes.map(dtype => (dtype._1, dtype._2)).toList
```

So the complete solution is as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val arrayToStringUdf = udf((array: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => array.mkString(", "))
def recursiveFunction(dataFrame: DataFrame, dataTypes: List[Tuple2[String, String]]) : DataFrame = dataTypes match {
  case x :: y => if (x._2.contains("ArrayType")) {
      recursiveFunction(dataFrame.withColumn(x._1, arrayToStringUdf(col(x._1))), y)
    }
    else{
      recursiveFunction(dataFrame, y)
    }
  case _ => dataFrame
}
val dataTypes = df.dtypes.map(dtype => (dtype._1, dtype._2)).toList

recursiveFunction(df, dataTypes).show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: could you clarify why we need a recursive function? Is it to handle the case that one of the elements inside the item itself might be an array?

Comment: @tldr,  recursive function is suggested to loop through the columns and check for datatypes and most importantly to use .withColumn api. I used recursive function to avoid using var.